# Node.JS server crashes

Tags: node.js

I have a problem, I'm creating app where you can buy tickets for cultural events. The problem is the server crashes when I try buying tickets when there is no tickets left. It gives this message: "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...".

```
try {
    const { email, firstName, lastName, phoneNumber } = req.body;
    const id = req.query.id;
    let eventFound: any;
    const event = await Event.findById(id, (error, result) => {
      if(!error)  eventFound = result;
      else throw new Error(error.message);
    });
    Ticket.find({ eventId: event?.id }, (error, tickets) => {
      if (!error) {
        if (event?.toJSON().maxTicketsAmount - 1 < tickets.length) {
          throw new Error("Not enough tickets");
        }
      }
    });
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: eventFound.ticketPrice, // NEEDS TO BE ABOVE SOME VALUE!!!!!!!
      currency: "pln",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
      receipt_email: email,
      metadata: { integration_check: "accept a payment" },
    });
    console.log(paymentIntent);
    const ticket = new Ticket({
      email: email,
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      eventId: eventFound.id,
      purchaseDate: new Date(),
    });
    ticket.save((error) => {
      if (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    });
    res.status(200).send(paymentIntent.client_secret);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: error.message });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is because you are throwing the error:

```js
 Ticket.find({ eventId: event?.id }, (error, tickets) => {
      if (!error) {
        if (event?.toJSON().maxTicketsAmount - 1 < tickets.length) {
          throw new Error("Not enough tickets");
        }
      }
```

and then it is getting "catched" in the `try/catch` statement. As a result you are manually crashing the server. Instead you should:

```
Ticket.find({ eventId: event?.id }, (error, tickets) => {
      if (!error) {
        if (event?.toJSON().maxTicketsAmount - 1 < tickets.length) {
          res.status(404).send("no more tickets")
        }
      }
```